# How to set unique constraint in a hasMany relationship

Tags: grails, groovy, many-to-many, constraints, has-many

I have this class:

```
class Word {
  String word

  static hasMany = [group: WordGroup]
  static belongsTo = [language: Language]    


  static constraints = {
    word(unique: ['language'], maxSize:255)
  }
}
```

Which is working fine, but I would need to associate the unique constraint to both language and group, so different groups can insert the same "word".

The groups are in an intermediate table (WordGroup) as this is a many to many relationship.

If I try to do

```
word(unique: ['language', 'group'], maxSize:255)
```

I get the error

```
Missing IN or OUT parameter in index:: 3
```

Is there a way to do this?

EDIT: I am adding the other classes referenced in the Word class if it helps

WordGroup

```
class WordGroup {
  static belongsTo = [word: Word, group: Group]

  static constraints = {}
}
```

Group

```
class Group {
  String name
  String url

  static hasMany = [words: Word]

  static constraints = {
    name blank: false, unique: true
  }
}
```

Language

```
class Language {
  String name
  String code

  static constraints = {
    name maxSize:255
    code maxSize:255
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you also post the classes WorkGroup and Language? I created a Grails project (3.2.6) with your Word class and my own versions of WordGroup and Language and received no errors.

Comment: @Roland, I have added the classes referenced in the class Word.

Comment: It still works for me. When do you receive this error?

Comment: @Roland, when I try to save a new Word in the database, with the instruction: `wordInstance.save(flush: true)`

Comment: Could you post the code that creates the wordInstance before you save it?

Comment: @Roland, it's the standard code of the save() method: `def wordInstance = new Word(params)` `if (!wordInstance.save(flush: true)) { ...` This code works well until I add 'group' to the constraint

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139449/discussion-between-roland-and-marcos-fernandez).